# Math needed for undergrad Statistical Mechanics/Thermal Physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, soft-question, education, mathematics

A professor recommended me to take a course on Statistical Physics as preparation for agent-based computing in social sciences.

Now I have no experience in physics beyond basic highschool, and mathematics I have taken several discrete math courses (for computer science) and no calculus yet. I have had basic differentiation/trigonometry/integration in high school as well.

What math/physics do i need to be able to understand undergrad stat mechanics?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

(btw. I am already planning to take classical mechanics, because that's what the university states as prerequisite)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Well, it depends how far you want to go, but there is no way you can achieve a deep understanding of stat. mech. without having at least a reasonable understanding of probability theory...

Answer (score 10):

Depending on what your undergraduate class focuses on you will need some mathematical background in the following:

1. **Basic probability theory**: Some idea of permutations, probability distributions, mean and variance etc. Depending on how statistical the class gets you might need more.
2. **Partial Differentiation**: For the thermal physics side of things, a solid understanding of partial derivatives is key. Even though this is usually taught in a multivariable calculus class, you can easily pick this up if you understand basic derivatives, but don't underestimate its usefulness.
3. **Basic Series Expansions**: Approximations are everything, if you can't find an exact answer, a good approximation is the next best thing. Be able to expand simple polynomials and trigonometric functions. [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is also used quite often.

For the physics side of things:

1. **Basic Kinematics**: Understanding of introductory physics ideas about force, momentum and energy. Basic systems like harmonic oscillators.
2. **Quantization**: Again depending on how in depth the class is, but it can be good to have an idea about quantization in physics. eg: [de Broglie relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#de_Broglie_relations)

This is not meant to be exhaustive, but a list of things that I remember being useful. Some basic chemistry might also be useful, but probably not necessary. I would strongly recommend talking to the professor teaching it to get a good idea of what to expect.