# How do I self-study physics at the undergrad level?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mathematical-physics, education

I'm a new physics undergrad worried that I won't be able to learn everything I want at the university I'm going to.

Basically the Institute I'm going to is applied sciences focused, and all electives that are offered have to do with nanotech, electronics, solid state physics nuclear engineering etc. They don't offer any minors in math or elective courses like Particle Physics 1 & 2, Quantum field theory, General relativity etc, that I'd like to learn about.

I want to ask for resource recommendations to self study these things. It'd also be helpful if I could get a list of important math topics to cover that will help me build a strong base for this. And just in general, because I want to be really good at what I'm doing.

Maybe this comes off as too naively enthusiastic but I ask this because I hope to aim for someplace really good for my Master's and am keeping in mind internships too. So I want all the advice I can get on how to develop better skills and be well prepared.

Comment: What is the Institute you're attending? What degree? We probably could have more details about the suggestions given to you

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234/2451 and links therein.

Comment: try MIT site https://ocw.mit.edu/search/?d=Physics&s=department_course_numbers.sort_coursenum